# Cannot include child table after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, include, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I have two related tables:

**OrderHeader**

- Id
- Truck_name
- Group

**OrderItem**

- Id
- OrderID
- Location
- Read

OrderItem contains column OrderHeaderId (foreign key relationship).
My WebService has to select specific Order with orderItems and return it(after some parsing) to client. I have to use eager loading because of important data in OrderItem.My database query needs to load first not finished (Status IN 1402,1403 AND Read=0) order. So:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var query = context.OrderHeader
     .Where(o=> new[] { 1402, 1403 }.Contains(o.Status) && o.OrderItem.Any(g => g.Read == 0))
     .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
     .GroupBy(g => g.Group)
     .FirstOrDefault()
     .AsQueryable()
     .Include("OrderItem");
```

**I use GroupBy to take first not finished Group and every time it returns me an empty OrderItem table. Why? How to include child table after GroupBy statement?**

Comment: What exactly is Group? From the looks of it you're including the column OrderItem which does not exist in the OrderHeader table.

Comment: Group is an int column in database. OrderItem is table referenced to OrderHeader in EF